# SSH permission denied from Windows to GitLab (public key)

Tags: git, ssh

I'm trying to connect to GitLab from Microsoft Windows using ssh but in response to this command `ssh -Tvvv git@gitlab.markitasdone.com` I'm getting the following error:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Saeed/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "gitlab.markitasdone.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.markitasdone.com [142.93.9.7] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Saeed/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Saeed/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.markitasdone.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from gitlab.markitasdone.com
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Saeed/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: reserved 0
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31

debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from gitlab.markitasdone.com
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Saeed/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 142.93.9.7
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Saeed/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host 'gitlab.markitasdone.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:oG6rH82EthXFIeexWntA7mmsYb+h/d5lMGXc+2REW0k
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:oG6rH82EthXFIeexWntA7mmsYb+h/d5lMGXc+2REW0k
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Saeed/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@gitlab.markitasdone.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

It is worth noting that I was able to connect to GitLab just one month ago with no problem. Today, when I got the above error, I decided to remove the ssh key and generated another key following [GitLab instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#add-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account).

From the error, it seems like it's looking for a config file inside the ssh folder. I checked the folder but there's no such file there. Is it mandatory to create a config file for ssh to be able to work again? If so, what content should this file have?

Update:
The output of `ls -l` command inside the `.ssh` directory is:

```
total 12
-rw------- 1 saeed saeed 399 Jan 16 18:30 id_ed25519
-rw-r--r-- 1 saeed saeed  91 Jan 16 18:30 id_ed25519.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 saeed saeed 888 Jan 16 10:20 known_hosts
```

and the output of `id` is:

```
uid=1000(saeed) gid=1000(saeed) groups=1000(saeed),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),117(netdev)
```

Comment: I think it would be nice to contact `gitlab.markitasdone.com` sharing this error with them. They could inspect their server-side log telling you more information about your case.

Comment: Yes, I think I should do so. I've tested everything I could think of. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome in StackOverflow.

This is the interesting part of your log message:

```
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Saeed/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Saeed/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
```

For some reasons (it's up to you to understand why) that path cannot be accessed. Try opening your file manager and go to that location.

Maybe you have not generated the key from that computer or from that user account, in order to:

1. verify that the directory `/Users/Saeed/.ssh` exists
2. verify that the file `C:/Users/Saeed/.ssh/id_rsa` exists

If not, see how to generate a new SSH key.

Comment: I had originally created `id_ed25519` keys and they were in the directory. Alas, I got the above error. This time, I created an RSA key but now, it's asking for `id_rsa-cert`: `debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Saeed/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Saeed/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2`

Comment: Can you double-check that pathname or whatever its name to see if it really exists or if you can open these files using a text editor etc.?

Comment: There's no `id_rsa_cert` file in this directory but there are now `id_ed25519` and `id_rsa` keys in the directory (along with their `.pub` versions and a `known_hosts` file). I can open them using a text editor. There's valid content in them.

Comment: I have ubuntu under WSL2. I created another key there. Tried to verify the connection and I still get `Permission denied (publickey)`.  Interesting lines of the debugging output log: `debug1: identity file /home/saeed/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3` , `debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/saeed/.ssh/known_hosts:3` , `debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/saeed/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/saeed/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory`

Comment: Again it says "No such file or directory". Does it exist '/home/saeed/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk' ? Can you open it with a text editor? Can you show us its permmissions with: `id` and then `ls -l /home/saeed/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk`? Please put this in your question. Thank you

Comment: Nope, there's no such file in the `.ssh` directory. I've added the output of the `ls -l` and `id` commands to the question.